# $g(x) = \lim_{y \to x} f(y)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\lim_{y
>  \to x} f(y)$ exists for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $g:
>  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \lim_{y \to x} f(y)$ is
>   continuous. (source problem: Spivak chapter 6)

**My attempt**:

Fix $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)- g(a)| < \epsilon/2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ (such $\delta$ exists because $g(a) = \lim_{y \to a} f(y)$)

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-a| < \delta/2$.

Choose $\delta' > 0$ such that $|f(y)-g(x)| < \epsilon/2$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < |y-x| < \delta'$ (such $\delta'$ exists because $\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = g(x)$)

Pick $z \in \mathbb{R}- \{a\}$ satisfying $0 < |z-x| < \min \{\delta/2, \delta'\}$.

Then, we have $0 <|z-a| \leq |z-x|+|x-a|  < \delta$, hence $|f(z)-g(a)| < \epsilon/2$ and we also have $|g(x)-f(z)|< \epsilon/2$.

Hence, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-a| < \delta/2$, we have $|g(x)-g(a)| \leq |g(x)-f(z)| + |f(z) - g(a)| < \epsilon$

and we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are completely leaving out any reasoning for the existence of the $\delta$'s in some cases it is in my opinion at least partly non-trivial that they exist. This does depend a bit on the definition of limit too though I suppose for the usual one a lot of the deltas exist easilly.

Comment: I use the standard definition for limits $lim f(x) = l \iff \forall \epsilon >0: \exists \delta >0: \forall x: 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) -l| < \epsilon$ and similarly for continuity. I added the explanation for the deltas. Is it correct now?

Comment: It is much simpler to use the inequality $$g(a)-\epsilon <f(y) <g(a) +\epsilon $$ whenever $0<|y-a|<\delta$ and take limits as $y\to x$ where $x$ is some fixed point with $0<|x-a|<\delta$. This gives $$g(a) - \epsilon\leq g(x) \leq g(a) +\epsilon$$ and we are done.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh. Thanks for your comment. But is my approach correct too?

Comment: Yes your proof is correct.