# Can nested limits be flattened into a single limit?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Is it true that

$$\lim_{x \to c}{\Bigl(\lim_{y \to x}{g(y)}\Bigr)}=L \implies \lim_{y \to c}{g(y)}=L$$

(assuming $\lim_{y \to x}{g(y)}$ exists for all $x$)

---

The question crossed my mind when doing a problem to do with derivatives. Specifically, the problem of whether

$$\lim_{x \to c}{f^\prime(x)} = L \implies f^\prime(c) = L$$

since expanding $f^\prime$ using the definition of a derivative yields something a lot like the expression this question asks about:

$$\lim_{x \to c}{\Bigl(\lim_{y \to x}{\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}}\Bigr)}=L \implies \lim_{y \to c}{\frac{f(y)-f(c)}{y-c}}=L$$

(assuming that inner limit always exists, i.e. assuming that $f$ is differentiable for all $x$)

Comment: I think it is only required that the limit exist in some neighborhood of $c$ (it doesn't need to exist for all $x$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. [If $\lim_{y\to x} g(y) $ exists for all $x$ then the function $G(x) =\lim_{y\to x} g(y) $ is continuous for all $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2876236/72031). Now your hypothesis is $\lim_{x\to c} G(x) =L$ and by continuity of $G$ this means $G(c) =L$ which is same as saying $\lim_{y\to c} g(y) =L$.

BTW, this does not apply to the case of derivatives because then you don't have a function of type $g(y) $. The ratio $$\frac{f(y) - f(x)} {y-x} $$ can not be conceived as a function of just $y$ as the variable $x$ is also present in the ratio.

The right approach to deal with the result on derivatives is mean value theorem and you should try that.

Comment: I see now it's not trivial. Nice comment in link.